# My object is returning an answer using another object's parameters

Tags: java

Whenever you use charAt() for a string containing numbers, it returns 48 + the digit stored at that index. Why exactly?

Ex:

```
import java.util.*;
public class otherApples {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String neuwt = scan.nextLine();
        int i = neuwt.charAt(2);
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

```
intput: 523
output: 51
```

Comment: try `neuwt.charAt(2) - '0'`

Comment: What output did you expect? What would you expect for "ABC"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the character '3' has the ASCII character code 51.

If `i` were a `char` you would get the `3` you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Character '0' has ASCII code 48. '1' is 49 and so on.

In other words: `'0' == 48`. What you are seeing is correct, you are just looking at the ASCII codes and not the actual characters those codes represent.